# Eloquent Pivot Relationship with 2 tables

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, relational-database, eloquent

I'm not sure if this can be done, But I have 2 tables:

```
parts:
id      part_number     description             multiplier  kit   type
===============================================================================
2012    ADH01-PRCD01-E  Program disc            1.00        0     3 
2013    ADH01-STHO01-E  Objectives Worksheet    1.00        0     3 
2014    ADH01-STPT01-E  Student Post-test vA    1.00        0     3 
2015    ADH01-STPT02-E  Student Post-test vB    1.00        0     3

kit_parts:
id   kit_id   part_id
======================
1    2012    2013
2    2012    2014
3    2012    2015
```

If kit is set in the parts table, then it needs to look at kit parts to know what is also included.

I'm trying to figure out how to  make this a relation in Laravel with a single model.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works and allows for many to many relationship.

```
    public function kitParts() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Parts', 'kit_parts', 'kit_id', 'part_id');
    }
    public function partKits() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Parts', 'kit_parts', 'part_id', 'kit_id');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each part will only ever belong to one kit, you can do this in your Part model with a self-referencing one-to-many relation on the `kit` column:

```
public function kits()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Part', 'kit', 'kit');
}
```

For any individual part (say, part #2012), you can obtain all the parts in its kit with:

```
$kitParts = Part::find(2012)->kits;
```

---

If you need to retrieve associated parts as part of a query for multiple parts, you can eager load the relation to avoid having to run the kit query for each part in the result set:

```
$parts = Part::with('kits')->get();
```

...so each element of the result set `$parts` will now have a `kits` attribute that you can access:

```php
foreach($parts as $part) {
    //the part
    foreach ($part->kits as $kit) {
    // the parts in this kit
    }
}
```